# cd %C^ in command promt?

Tags: cmd

I khow im a bit off topic because posting here,but this is prety weird.
i were just testing cmd,when i enter this command:cd %C^
it show :
"more?"
"more?"
"The system cannot find the path specified."
this is weird because it is showing "more?",so i have tried researching on the internet,but found thin air.
screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejxrv.jpg
is this normal?

Comment: *coding some batch file* isn't helpful when you're asking a question related to the output  of that code. Please [edit] your question to include the actual code you're using, in the form of a [mre]. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if  you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: The caret `^` masks the following line feed, resulting in the end of the physical line, but not in the end of the logical line ("incomplete command"). So the parser asks you to continue the logical line. Testcase: `C:\>ec^` [Enter]; `More? ho` [Enter]-> `Echo is ON`. Useful for splitting a long command line into several physical lines for readability (quite the opposite with the shown `echo` command - that's just to show the principle)

Comment: @ken white The reason why I mentioned "batch file" because i am coding a batch script that create some patch-classes to a java agent.because of it i must test the arguments in cmd before type in batch.

Comment: I know why you mentioned *batch file*, and I pointed out why just saying *batch file* is useless information. We need to see the **code** from that batch file when you're asking  questions about that code or what it does. If you're not asking about code in a batch  file, then don't discuss batch files in your question. Also, for future reference: Do not add image links except by using the *Insert image* button on the toolbar. All images must be stored in SO's imgur space so that they remain available in the future, and you've used a different imgur space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"More?" means the cmd is asking you to continue your command.

"^" is an escape character when you use this character the cmd does not just runs whole command and shows you the result but instead **it breaks the command in parts that it will run as you press enter key when it says "more?" it asks you if you want to run the next part of the command** and **at the end it reaches at the same result as writing a command as "cd %C"**.

if you have used linux you can see this type of interpretation when you open a large file using cat(a file reading function in bash that prints out the text file as you press ***enter***).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).